# i want to add the while loop function to my code

Tags: python

i successfully ran the following code, but i was wondering whether i can
add while loop to my code to make my program ask for another word after the user enters a word.

```
import json
from difflib import get_close_matches


data = json.load(open("data.json"))

def meaning(w):
    w = w.lower()
    if w in data:
        return data[w]
    elif len(get_close_matches(w, data.keys())) > 0:
        answer = input("Did you mean %s instead. Press Y if yes or Press N if no: " % get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0])
        if answer == "Y":
           return data[get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0]]
        elif answer == "N":
           return "The word doesn't exist. Please Check again."
        else:
           return "The word doesn't exist in english dictionary."
    else:
        return "The word doesn't exist. Please Check again."



word = input("Enter a word: ")


output = meaning(word)


if type(output) == list:
    for items in output:
        print(items)
else:
    print(output)
input()
```

i am expecting the program to ask the user to enter another word after he enters a word and gets a result.

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/

Comment: `while` is not a function, but a loop that repeats a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import json
from difflib import get_close_matches


data = json.load(open("data.json"))

def meaning(w):
    w = w.lower()
    if w in data:
        return data[w]
    elif len(get_close_matches(w, data.keys())) > 0:
        answer = input("Did you mean %s instead. Press Y if yes or Press N if no: " % get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0])
        if answer == "Y":
           return data[get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0]]
        elif answer == "N":
            return "The word doesn't exist. Please Check again."
        else:
            return "The word doesn't exist in english dictionary."
    else:
        return "The word doesn't exist. Please Check again."


word = ""
while word != "q":
    word = input("Enter a word or q to quit: ")


    output = meaning(word)


    if type(output) == list:
        for items in output:
            print(items)
    else:
        print(output)
```

This will keep looping until you enter q. I'm not sure what your json looks like so you may need some modification based on what the meaning function is doing.

Comment: This will loop one time *after* you enter `q`.

Comment: @Barmar did you run it and see this result? Because when I run it keeps looping until I enter a q.

Comment: i tried your code, but it is only looping through that piece of code and not the rest of the functions of the code.

Comment: When you say "the rest of the functions" do you mean it isn't running the meaning function, or you have other functions that you need to run in addition?

Answer (score 0):

Put a `while` loop around the code that asks for the input and processes it. Check for the end string and break out of the loop when you get it.

```
while True:
    word = input("Enter a word: ")
    if word == 'q':
        break

    output = meaning(word)
    if type(output) == list:
        for items in output:
            print(items)
    else:
        print(output)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Darshan\Documents\python\firstproject.py", line 26, in <module>
    while true:
NameError: name 'true' is not defined

Comment: It's `True` not `true`.

Comment: sorry my bad, am new to python. Thanks for your help